# Triangulate surface in 3D-space

Tags: algorithm, 3d, geometry, triangulation

I have a set of points(x,y,z) in space and from them i need to create a surface and triangulate it. In theory it should be something like parametric-generated surface.

I have tried projecting points on 2d, triangulate it and put it back in 3D, but this doesn't work for me, also tried few algoritms but main problem, that i have is all of them gives back polyhedron-shaped object, but my goal surface-shaped triangulated object. I need some help with algorithms/different approach to problem

Comment: All the points are on the same plane?

Comment: By "plane", do you mean "surface"?

Comment: @Makketronix yeah, sorry for my english

Comment: @user31264 no, they could be in different

Comment: Is the surface more or less smooth?  That is, for a point and several closest points, it is close to a plane?

Comment: add at least a plot of the points so we see what are you dealing with ... what about compute nearest few points for each point to make connectivity info and form some kind of grid. from that triangulation is easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement BallPivoting, give a look to: http://www.research.ibm.com/vistechnology/pdf/bpa_tvcg.pdf